# Draw circles that leave the image boundaries

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

imo=Image.new("RGB", (85, 64), (204, 204, 204))
pos=(10, 64)
r=8
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(imo)
draw.chord((pos[0]-r, pos[1]-r, pos[0]+r, pos[1]+r), 0, 359, (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0))

for pos in [(32, -1), (85, 32), (32, 64), (-1, 32), (54, 63)]:
  draw.ellipse((pos[0]-r, pos[1]-r, pos[0]+r, pos[1]+r), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0))

pos=(75, 65)
draw.rectangle((pos[0]-r, pos[1]-r, pos[0]+r, pos[1]+r), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0))

imo.save("aa.png", "PNG")
```

creates this (enlarged) image:

[image: the output of the python code, enlarged]

Is there a trick to draw the circles in such a way that they are also shown fully filled at the bottom of the image?
Okay...it works fine for rectangles...but I would prefer circles.

Comment: That code seems to work for me. The fill on the circles on the bottom edge goes all the way to the bottom edge. Just as another data point...

Comment: not for me. Tested with python-Pillow-2.8.1-3.6.1.x86_64 and python3-Pillow-3.4.2-45.2.x86_64. What version do you use?

Comment: I have now tried it with Pillow versions 4.1.1 and 3.4.2. Both on Python 3.6 and Linux. Both worked.

Comment: Just tried on Windows with Python 3.5 and Pillow 3.4.2 and that also worked. I should note that I only used pip/easy_install to install pillow. I suppose I could try the binary installers...

Comment: I now found, that it works with python-Pillow-2.9.0-6.4.x86_64 on Leap42.2. And it also works with python3-Pillow-3.4.2-45.2.x86_64 on openSUSE 13.2 (for my first comment, I changed the shebang to python3 but used python to start the script...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after upgrading to python-Pillow-2.9.0-6.4.x86_64, I now get fully filled circles - even on openSUSE 13.2.